# Error with version of libraries inside Build.Gradle

Tags: android, gradle

I f I add `implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:16.0.1'`
to my app build.gradle I get error both on that line and on `implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'`

```
All com.android.support libraries must use the exact same version 
specification (mixing versions can lead to runtime crashes). Found versions
 27.1.1, 26.1.0. Examples include com.android.support:animated-vector-
drawable:27.1.1 and com.android.support:support-media-compat:26.1.0

All gms/firebase libraries must use the exact same version specification 
(mixing versions can lead to runtime crashes). Found versions 16.0.1, 16.0.0,
 15.0.1. Examples include com.google.android.gms:play-services-
analytics:16.0.1 and com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-
base:16.0.0
```

How can I solve this problem?? I tried to manually edit the version of the library but I still get the same problem.

This is my Build.Gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 27
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.domain.app"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 27
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'

    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.2'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'

    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:27.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:27.1.1'
    compile 'com.facebook.stetho:stetho:1.4.2'

    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:16.0.1'



}
```

Comment: share your **`Build.Gradle`** with question

Comment: @NileshRathod I did it

Comment: `classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.0.1'`??

Comment: @IntelliJAmiya I still get the same problem even with  implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:16.0.0' and 
` classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.0.1'`

Comment: if set `implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:12.0.1'`

Comment: Im added 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:12.0.1' and I changed everything else to versionr 26.1.0. It seems to work

Comment: @MDP `analytics:16.0.1'` also working with `27.0.2` in my case

Comment: @MDP Hope so. Seems like its system level issue. Hope upcoming version overcome this.

Answer (score 1):

Change the version of the library in all the **Gradle** files(including imported projects). After that **clean and rebuild the project**. If you still get the error ignore it, as it will not affect your app.

Comment: What version should I use?

Answer (score 1):

You need to change the version of all your Gradle files to same version. This include all your native libraries plus the imported one.

Comment: What version should I use?

Comment: You can use the latest versions of the libraries which you can obviously find with the help of **Google**.

Answer (score 1):

You have to change the version (***com.android.support:design:27.1.1*** is the latest version now) of the library in all the Gradle files(including imported projects) and then you have to clean and rebuild the project.
Then replace all the 'compile' words with 'implementation' because configuration 'compile' is obsolete and has been replaced with 'implementation' and 'api'.

Answer (score 1):

> All com.android.support libraries must use the exact same version 
>   specification (mixing versions can lead to runtime crashes). Found
>   versions
>    27.1.1, 26.1.0. Examples include com.android.support:animated-vector- drawable:27.1.1 and com.android.support:support-media-compat:26.1.0

- At first, Use **`implementation`**  instead of **`compile`**.

**DOWNGRADE** your version

```
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:12.0.1'
```

**NOTE**

If the same problem coming, Downgrade **`v7:27.1.1`** to **`v7:26.1.0`** .